# the meaning of "two Es at A level"

Tags: meaning, british-english

> *In his recent, rather surprising ad hominem attack on Jeremy Corbyn, Martin Amis ranged a number of charges against the current Labour leader. Among them were his lack of education (**two Es at A level!**), his evident lack of “the slightest grasp of the national character” and his allegiance to the “encysted dogmas” of the old left.*

Here is the [source](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2015/oct/30/martin-amis-jeremy-corbyn-humour-jonathan-coe).

Can you explain to me in the most simplified way what is "two Es at A level". I understand that it has something to do with the system of education in the UK, namely the lower level of university education. But what precisely? Is it some type of bachelor's degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic [information about the UK Education system is well documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_the_United_Kingdom), but  I'll summarise here rather than suggest more research is required! :-)

[A-Levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCE_Advanced_Level_(United_Kingdom)) are one of the [various forms of University Entrance examinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/School_leaving_qualification) used in the nations of England, Wales and Northern Ireland.

These qualifications are graded A*,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,U,X, where A* is the highest grade of pass and E is the lowest.

The lowest possible qualification accepted by a UK University for entrance would be known as two-E's (or EE), which is a minimal pass at two subjects at A-level. Most candidates would do three or four subjects and be expected to get CCC or higher for university entrance. We would also denote EE as *basic matriculation*.

To have a qualification lower than EE would imply that the person had not properly completed their high school education successfully. To impune that someone only had EE would be considered that you were doubting their intelligence.